# Can not set property of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to write a route for generate otp. And first check the user exist. If user exist send otp. And if not than first save the user in db and then generate the otp. Also want to set time to live otp data in db for 360 seconds.
please tell me what I am doing wrong. when the below code is run it gives the error that can not set the property of null.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobileNo' of null

```
router.route('/generateOtp/:mobileNo').get(function (req, res) {
    Account.findOne({ mobileNo: req.params.mobileNo }, function (err, account) {

        //below is writeen to check if account exist with above mobile no
        if(account===null)
        { 
            account.mobileNo = req.body.mobileNo;

            //below for a is  random 4 digit code 
            account.OtpNo=a;

            //here i am trying to saving the otp and mobile no in mongo db
            newAccount.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                console.log("Account added");
            });

            //console.log(account);
        }


        else
        //if mobile no already exist than just gentating 4 digit code and saving to monodb
        {
            account.mobileNo = req.body.mobileNo;
            account.OtpNo = a;
            newAccount.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                console.log("Account added");
            });  
        }
    });
});
```

my schema is as follows:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    mobileNo:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    },
    OtpNo:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        //unique:true
        createdAt: 1,
        expireAfterSeconds: 300
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('account', AccountSchema);
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Also can you add error stracktrace to the question . No body have so much time to debug code .

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to set `mobileNo` on `null` account, so you are getting

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'mobileNo' of null

it should be

```
if( account === null )
{ 
    account = {}; // or create new account
    account.mobileNo = req.body.mobileNo;
    account.OtpNo = a;
    //save this account
}
```